# Ionic 6 - Capacitor Filesystem - copy SQLite files from ZIP

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, filesystems, capacitor, jszip

Hello everyone and thanks for taking time to read and answer.

## DESCRIPTION

I am using **Ionic 6** with **Angular 14** and **capacitor**. I need to copy the content of an ZIP file uploaded by the user (it contains **.sqlite files**), and store it inside the Documents folder. For that, I'm using **JSZip** library.

```js
  public async unzipFolder(file: File): Promise<string[]> {
    const zip: JSZip = await JSZip.loadAsync(file);
    const promises: Promise<string>[] = [];

    zip.forEach((relativePath: string, zipFile: JSZipObject) =>
        promises.push(this.unzipFile(zipFile));
    );
    return await Promise.all(promises);
  }

  public async unzipFile(compressedFile: JSZipObject): Promise<string> {
    return await compressedFile.async('string').then((data: string) => {
     this.fileOpsService.write(compressedFile.name, data)
    });
  }
```

Everything works fine here. Problems comes when I try to store it in Documents folder using **Filesystem plugin (capacitor)**.

```js
  public async write(
    path: string,
    data: string,
    directory: Directory = Directory.Documents
  ): Promise<WriteFileResult> {
    return await Filesystem.writeFile({
      path: path,
      directory: directory,
      data: data,
      recursive: false,
    });
  }
```

XCode's terminal throws this error:

```js
{"errorMessage":"Unable to save file"}
```

I tried File plugin (awasome-cordova-file) but it does not work.

```js
  public async write(
    path: string,
    data: ArrayBuffer,
    directory: Directory = Directory.Documents
  ): Promise<any> {
    return await File.writeFile(path, '', data, {replace: true})
  }
```

It throws the next error:

```
[DocumentManager] Failed to associate thumbnails for picked URL file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/XXX/File%20Provider%20Storage/TEST_BATCH2.zip with the Inbox copy file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/XXX/tmp/io.ionic.starter.ivan-Inbox/TEST_BATCH2.zip: Error Domain=QLThumbnailErrorDomain Code=102 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x282532cd0 {Error Domain=GSLibraryErrorDomain Code=3 "Generation not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=Generation not found}}}
```

## TESTED SOLUTIONS

1. I tried to **read the ZIP files as ArrayBuffer or Blob**, but the
   Filesystem plugin can only use string data, so it didn't work.
2. I also try to **change the encoding** value of Filesystem to UTF-8,
   UTF-16 and ASCII but it didn't work. The default value is Base64
   encoding.
3. I try to **use the cordoba File plugin**. In previous app versions this was working
   fine, so I try it (when the app used cordoba instead capacitor). Didn't work.

## THEORIES

1. I'm not sure about what is happening here, but seems than could be something related
   with encoding. Filesystem is not designed 4 copy .sqlite files I suppose.
2. Maybe something related with relative paths, but I don't think so.
3. Some Apple sh*t, u know...

### Notes

1. I just need it to work in iOS and Electron platforms. Browser could be a plus, but is not required.
2. I know that an API/REST approach could be better, but it's not posible for this app. **We need to store the data localy.**

Comment: This question helps me to find a solution to a similar problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After a few days, I finally found a solution. Here is it, if it can help anyone...

I changed the way of read from ZIP file by replacing 'string' with 'blob' as you can see in the following snippet:

```js
  public async unzipFile(compressedFile: JSZipObject): Promise<void> {
    return await compressedFile.async('blob').then(async (data: Blob) => {
      const filename: string = compressedFile.name
        .replace('.sqlite', 'SQLite.db');
      const base64 = await this.convertBlobToBase64(data);
      this.fileOpsService.write(filename, base64);
    });
  }
```

I create a convertBlobToBase64 helper function that looks like this:

```js
  private convertBlobToBase64 = (blob: Blob) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.onload = () => {
      resolve(reader.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  })
```

And it works! Note that I replaced the filename because I need it in that format to read it with another plugin =)