# Capacitor App, Extracting a Zip File Locally and accessing it

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have an Ionic/Capacitor application and wanted to be able to download a ZIP file locally onto the device, unzip it, and then serve the page within the Ionic/Capacitor app.
The ZIP file contains a zipped up static website. I'd like to be able to extract that website and view it via the app (i.e. offline mode).

Preferably supported on both iOS and Android.

Does Capacitor support this and what would be the strategy around doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use several solutions:

1. when developing an app that uses Capacitor, it's possible to use Cordova plugins. As said in https://github.com/danielsogl/awesome-cordova-plugins , Awesome Cordova Plugins also works with Capacitor, Ionic's official native runtime. The plugin https://danielsogl.gitbook.io/awesome-cordova-plugins/zip can be used to unzip file.
2. it's possible to use other js library to unzip. For instance, you can look at [Ionic 6 - Capacitor Filesystem - copy SQLite files from ZIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72867155/ionic-6-capacitor-filesystem-copy-sqlite-files-from-zip)

I don't explain option 1 here because I use option 2 in order to not use cordova plugin in my capacitor project.

I use JSZip to unzip (https://github.com/Stuk/jszip)

```
> npm install jszip
```

In your "service.ts", download your file with the help of Filesystem capacitor plugin:

```
 downloadRes = await Filesystem.downloadFile({
    path: pathRelativeTodirectory,
    directory: directory,
    url: urlOfTheZipFile,
```

Then, with jszip, you can extract all file of your zip and register these files if you want:

```
//read zip file
    let data = await Filesystem.readFile({
      path: pathRelativeTodirectory,
      directory: directory
    })

    let zipContent = await JSZip.loadAsync(data.data);
    //Unzip file and register all files on disk
    zipContent.forEach(async (relativePath: string, zipFile: JSZip.JSZipObject) => {
      console.log("Write file from zip " + relativePath);
      await Filesystem.writeFile({
          path: relativePath,
          directory: directory,
          data: await zipFile.async('blob'),
          recursive: true
      });          
    });
```

Comment: On android, the return of Filesystem.readFile is a string encoded in base64.
I use this method to transform it in blob



  private _converteBase64StringToBlob(data: string, dataForJSZip: string | Blob) {
    const byteCharacters = atob(data);
    const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    return new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/zip' });
  }

Comment: can we use password on zip in this ?

Comment: not yet, see jszip documentation https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/load_async.html :  "Zip features not (yet) supported : password protected zip"